# Getting “Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string” - when it is a string

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in my functions.php, which executes a script upon publish:

```
function save_new_post($post_ID) {

$site_root = '/home/forexmag/public_html/directory2';
$post = get_post($post_ID);
$title = $post->post_title;
$breaking_news = false;

$categories = get_the_category($post_ID);
if (is_array($categories) && !empty($categories))
{
    foreach ($categories as $cat_det)
    {
        //this is the id for the breaking (bad) news
        if (5668 == $cat_det->cat_ID)
        {
            $breaking_news = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$exec_code = "/usr/local/bin/php 
        $site_root 
        /crons/cron_notify.php '$title' $post_ID 2 " . intval($breaking_news);
exec(
    $exec_code
);
} add_action('draft_to_publish', 'save_new_post', 10, 1);
```

When I publish a new post I keep getting the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in /home/forexmag/public_html/wp-content/themes/forex_magnates/functions.php on line 712
```

This line is where I set the `$exec_code` var. However, as you can see, and as I confirmed via var_dump, the `$title` variable is a string. What am I missing?

EDIT: What's even weirder is that when I var_dump `$exec_code` and kill the script, I get a perfect string:

```
string(121) "/usr/local/bin/php /home/forexmag/public_html/directory2/crons/cron_notify.php '2011 Free Forex Report' 9934 2 0"
```

Comment: Can you confirm if `$post_ID` is a string?

Comment: It is an integer. But shouldn't it be converted to a string when concatenated?

Comment: @Jrod, you were right. I tested with the publish_page hook, which gives an int, whereas the draft_to_publish one uses an object

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got the correct answer on Wordpress Answers. Thought I should share it:

`$post_ID` is a `WP_Post` object. Your exec code should effectively be using `$post_ID->ID.`

```
function save_new_post($post_ID)
{
    print_r($post_ID);
    die();
```

Returns

```
WP_Post Object ( [ID] => ...
```

Courtesy of [vancoder](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26778/vancoder)

Do notice that this depends on the hook you are using. E.g if you use `publish_page` you get an integer (This was actually the source of my confusion)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, however the solution to my problem in the end was

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This was because WP_Query was being used and was interrupting the rest of the queries further down the page.

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score -2):

I got that same error on my website one day but the code wasn't the problem. The problem lies in the database. What I did was go into my database and change the siteurl and home because there was gibberish inside it. I think my website was compromise so I change the database password. This website will help you to get rid of the catchable fatal error https://www.msgdigital.com/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-wp_error-could-not-be-converted-to-string/ .

I tried it and trust me it worked.