# Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string

Tags: php, wordpress, string

I think I may have a similar problem to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009005/getting-object-of-class-wp-post-could-not-be-converted-to-string-when-it-is) but I don't know how to apply the solution / if I truly have the same problem. I'm so new that I have no idea what I could do with the suggested solutions. In answering my problem I hope you will be extremely elaborate. Please instruct me step by step.

**It all started when I activated this plugin:** Tin Canny LearnDash Reporting

**It resulted in this error:**

```
WordPress database error Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes. for query ALTER TABLE wp_posts ENGINE=INNODB made by activate_plugin, include_once('/plugins/tin-canny-learndash-reporting/tin-canny-learndash-reporting.php'), include_once('/plugins/tin-canny-learndash-reporting/src/uncanny-articulate-and-captivate/storyline-and-captivate.php'), TINCANNYSNC\\Init->__construct, TINCANNYSNC\\Init->check_upgrade, TINCANNYSNC\\Database->upgrade, call_user_func, TINCANNYSNC\\Database::create_table_snc_post_relationship\n, referer: https://www.lets-grow.today/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
```

**After previous feedback from host/plugin developer/reddit users, I tried running this query in SQL:**

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

**Now I have this new error when opening a quiz that's not part of a lesson or step in Learndash (LMS):**

```
Backend log: PHP Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in /home/debXXXXXXX/domains/lets-grow.today/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sfwd-lms/includes/classes/class-ldlms-course-steps.php on line 910\n, referer: https://www.lets-grow.today/tasks-projects/3hv-y-ch-02-knowledge-of-history/quizzes/uk-02-history/
```

**I tried to load a backup but the error persists.**

**This is Line 910:**

```
$steps_key = $post_type .':'. $post_id;
```

**Someone on Reddit tried to help saying:** `$post_type` isn't a string, and cannot be made a string. Where does `$post_type` come from?

**This may the answer to my problem but I don't know what to do with the answer:**

> $post_ID is a WP_Post object. Your exec code should effectively be
>   using $post_ID->ID.
>
> function save_new_post($post_ID) {
>       print_r($post_ID);
>       die(); Returns
>
> WP_Post Object ( [ID] => ... Courtesy of vancoder
>
> Do notice that this depends on the hook you are using. E.g if you use
>   publish_page you get an integer (This was actually the source of my
>   confusion)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not sure this is the right place for your query - this is a forum for programmers with specific coding questions, but your problem is being caused by a very specific issue with a specific plugin you installed. It's impossible for us to know what is happening without seeing the code, so unfortunately I'm not sure you'll get the expertise you need here.

Comment: However this really is something the plugin developer should be fixing at for you, especially as it is a paid-for plugin. In all honesty, I'm a bit dubious of the advice they already gave you about altering the table (it's generally a very bad idea to change WP's internal setup), but I don't know the plugin so I can't be sure. But either way, they have sold you the plugin, and they are the experts so they are in the best position to help. I hope you get the help you need!